# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with an onclick function on it. When clicked upon I get the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined`

The strange thing is that 3 out of 5 rows the `class` is changed, but 2/5 are not. When clicked again on the row, one of the remaining two is changed and when clicked again the last one is changed. Here's my code:

**HTML table**

```
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard row5' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '6', '5')"><td><input type='checkbox' name='strFormFactuur[]' value='19500' id='chk6'>&nbsp;<img src='../images/link.png' border='0'></td>    
    <td><img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;' onClick="saveData('6', '?iID=19500&bType=0', 'all');")> <input type='image' src='../images/toevoegen.png' border='0' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;' name='FormDupliceer' value='19500'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard row5' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '7', '5')"><td></td>    
    <td><img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;' onClick="saveData('7', '?iID=36&bType=1', 'fltBedrag');"> <input type='image' src='../images/b_delete.png' border='0' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;' name='FormVerwijder' value='36'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard row5' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '8', '5')"><td></td>    
    <td><img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;' onClick="saveData('8', '?iID=37&bType=1', 'fltBedrag');"> <input type='image' src='../images/b_delete.png' border='0' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;' name='FormVerwijder' value='37'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard row5' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '9', '5')"><td></td>    
    <td><img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;' onClick="saveData('9', '?iID=38&bType=1', 'fltBedrag');"> <input type='image' src='../images/b_delete.png' border='0' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;' name='FormVerwijder' value='38'></td>    
</tr>
<tr class='invoice-tr-standard row5' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '10', '5')"><td></td>    
    <td><img src='../images/b_save.png' border='0' height='13px' style='cursor: pointer;' onClick="saveData('10', '?iID=66&bType=1', 'fltBedrag');"> <input type='image' src='../images/b_delete.png' border='0' style='float: right; cursor: pointer;' name='FormVerwijder' value='66'></td>    
</tr>
```

The javascript function `FormTRClick()`:

```
function FormTRClick(event, uID, PCID) {
    var Object= event.target.tagName;   
    if (Object == 'TD') {
        var Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('row' + PCID);
        var iNumElements = Elements.length;
        alert(iNumElements); // Outputs 5 as expected
        for (var i=0; i < iNumElements; i++) {
            Elements[i].className = "invoice-tr-clicked"; // Only changes 3 out of 5 on the first click         
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

When using the following `Elements[i].className += " invoice-tr-clicked";` instead of `Elements[i].className = "invoice-tr-clicked";`, the script works as it should. But when replacing (hence the `=`) I get the `Cannot set property 'className' of undefined` error.

Comment: I tried to reconstruct your example here: http://jsbin.com/ugojaj/edit#javascript,html
But I could not reproduce the error.
Could you provide a working SSCCE?

Comment: @Ben I've changed the code a little bit and it works as expected, but not in my environment. This code works: http://jsbin.com/ugojaj/2 I have to play around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by replacing

```
 Elements[i].className = "invoice-tr-clicked";
```

with

```
 Elements[i].className = "invoice-tr-clicked row" + PCID;
```

Doesn't make any sense it works now, since the [demo](http://jsbin.com/ugojaj/4) works without problems.